# Create external content type with impersonated custom identity

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, bcs, external-content-type, external-list

I'm developing a SharePoint Application. I have SharePoint Foudation 2010. I have created a External Content Type with Impersonated Custom Identity(Connection to SQL Server 2012). After I created a list(function Create Lists and Form).

The problem is that: I can't view data from my list. I know that SharePoint required the service SSS(Secured Store Service) for this type of connection.

Anyone can explain me, how I can resolve my problem?

The error is "access denied by business data connectivity", when I try to view my List.

I followed this istruction http://zimmergren.net/technical/access-denied-by-business-data-connectivity-solution. Now I have this error:

> Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open
>   this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML
>   editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists,
>   contact your Web server administrator.
>
> Correlation ID:8cb329a8-e844-4403-9c1e-d7dd62ba50ae

Result of SharePoint's log file:

> InnerException 1: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its
>   dependencies. Impossibile trovare il file specificato.  File name:
>   'Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'     at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle._GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)     at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark)     at
>   System.RuntimeType.PrivateGetType(String typeName, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolea...

Comment: What error did you get.?

Comment: The error is "access denied by business data connectivity".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is resolved. I follow this [Link](http://wyldesharepoint.blogspot.it/2010/06/setting-up-external-content-type-for.html). The cause is that SharePoint 2010 Foudation don't include SSS(Secure Store Service). I have modified my ECT with a text editor.